# Laravel caching authenticated user's relationships

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, caching, laravel-5

In my application I use Laravel's authentication system and I use dependency injection (or the Facade) to access the logged in user. I tend to make the logged in user accessible through my base controller so I can access it easily in my child classes:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = \Auth::user();
    }
}
```

My user has a number of different relationships, that I tend to eager load like this:

```
$this->user->load(['relationshipOne', 'relationshipTwo']);
```

As in this project I'm expecting to receive consistently high volumes of traffic, I want to make the application run as smoothly and efficiently as possible so I am looking to implement some caching.

I ideally, need to be able to avoid repeatedly querying the database, particularly for the user's related records. As such I need to look into caching the user object, after loading relationships.

I had the idea to do something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $userId = \Auth::id();
    if (!is_null($userId)) {
        $this->user = \Cache::remember("user-{$userId}", 60, function() use($userId) {
            return User::with(['relationshipOne', 'relationshipTwo'])->find($userId);
        });
    }
}
```

However, I'm unsure whether or not it's safe to rely on whether or not `\Auth::id()` returning a non-null value to pass authentication. Has anyone faced any similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you used a package like the following one. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache

It caches the response and you can use it for more than just the user object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some messing about I've come up with kind of a solution for myself which I thought I would share.

I thought I would give up on caching the actual `User` object, and just let the authentication happen as normal and just focus on trying to cache the user's relations. This feels like quite a dirty way to do it, since my logic is in the model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    // ..

    /**
     * This is the relationship I want to cache
     */
    public function related()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Related::class);
    }

    /**
     * This method can be used when we want to utilise a cache
     */
    public function getRelated()
    {
        return \Cache::remember("relatedByUser({$this->id})", 60, function() {
            return $this->related;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Do something with the cached relationship
     */
    public function totalRelated()
    {
        return $this->getRelated()->count();
    }
}
```

In my case, I needed to be able to cache the related items inside the `User` model because I had some methods inside the user that would use that relationship. Like in the pretty trivial example of the `totalRelated` method above (My project is a bit more complex).

Of course, if I didn't have internal methods like that on my `User` model it would have been just as easy to call the relationship from outside my model and cache that (In a controller for example)

```
 class MyController extends Controller
 {
      public function index()
      {
           $related = \Cache::remember("relatedByUser({$this->user->id})", 60, function() {
                return $this->user->related;
           });

           // Do something with the $related items...
      }
 }
```

Again, this doesn't feel like the best solution to me and I am open to try other suggestions.

Cheers

---

**Edit:** I've went a step further and implemented a couple of methods on my parent `Model` class to help with caching relationships and implemented getter methods for all my relatonships that accept a `$useCache` parameter, to make things a bit more flexible:

Parent Model class:

```
class Model extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * Helper method to get a value from the cache if it exists, or using the provided closure, caching the result for
     * the default cache time.
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param Closure|null $callback
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function cacheRemember($key, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        return Cache::remember($key, Cache::getDefaultCacheTime(), $callback);
    }

    /**
     * Another helper method to either run a closure to get a value, or if useCache is true, attempt to get the value
     * from the cache, using the provided key and the closure as a means of getting the value if it doesn't exist.
     *
     * @param $useCache
     * @param $key
     * @param Closure $callback
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getOrCacheRemember($useCache, $key, Closure $callback)
    {
        return !$useCache ? $callback() : $this->cacheRemember($key, $callback);
    }
}
```

My User class:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function related()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Related::class);
    }

    public function getRelated($useCache = false)
    {
        return $this->getOrCacheRemember($useCache, "relatedByUser({$this->id})", function() {
            return $this->related;
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$related = $user->getRelated(); // Gets related from the database
$relatedTwo = $user->getRelated(true); // Gets related from the cache if present (Or from database and caches result)
```